# jQuery validation fails when putting step="1" in a "datetime-local" input type

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm using https://jqueryvalidation.org/ form validation plugin

When I put `step="1"` in a `datetime-local` input field to show seconds, if I'm validating that field with the plugin (just "required", for example), I get a javascript error saying "Step attribute on input type datetime-local is not supported". If I put this step="1" in a field that is not being validated, it works without problems.

```js
$("#testingform").validate();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="testingform">
    <input type="datetime-local" step="1" name="date1" required>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

... just put a date and time WITH SECONDS, and click 'Send' button. You can see the error in the console.

I've already opened a bug in the github page of the project, but maybe any of you had the same problem and have found a way to solve it or at least avoid it for the moment until they fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery validate automatically apply rules on input type, so **step** cannot be validated.

This will help you:

```js
$("#testingform").validate({
  rules: {
    date1: {step: false}
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="testingform">
    <input type="datetime-local" step="1" name="date1" required>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, man!! It works!! So, apparently, the plugin is interpreting the html `step` attribute of datetime-local that allows to use seconds as a validation rule (that is still not supported), right?