# Set rule for unobtrusive validation for ignoring step attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a form in which user is required to select date of birth. As date picker I´m using [flatpickr](https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr), which on mobile devices creates new input field that uses native mobile date picker. The created element looks like this:

```
<input type="date" step="any" min="..." max="...">
```

I'm also using JQuery unobtrusive validation, but form validation crashes with following error:

`Step attribute on input type date is not supported`

I found a [solution](https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr/issues/956) for this error:

```
onReady: (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) => {
    if (instance.isMobile) {
        $(instance.mobileInput).removeAttr("step");
    }
}
```

but step attribute is completely removed from the input, which is not nice. And this error is more connected to unobtrusive validation, not flatpickr. Another solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46485500/5632590) and I think is better, adds new validation rule:

```
$("#testingform").validate({
    rules: {
        date1: {step: false}
    }
});
```

I know this validation is for native JQuery validation, but for simplicity I present this. (You can access the unobtrusive validation rules by `$("form").validate().settings`.) However this solution is valid only for one specific field with `name="date1"`. Is it somehow possible to set unobtrusive validation rule which says something like "Ignore all step attributes"?

**Edit:**
I tried the solution proposed by @Sparky, however it does not worked. I tried to play around with rules for different inputs and I was not able to remove any of them. It seems that when using unobtrusive wrapper the `.rules("remove",...)` does not work. Actually I was able to remove the rule with following code `delete jq("form").validate().settings.rules["NameOfInput"].step`. However this does not work for my case, because flatpickr creates new input after initialization without name, so I cannot access it via `jq("form").validate().settings.rules`

Comment: *"flatpickr creates new input after initialization without name"* <- and that's your whole problem.  The jQuery Validation plugin mandates that every field considered for validation must have a `name` attribute.  There is no workaround for a missing `name` attribute without re-writing the core of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

[Did you look at the docs for the jQuery Validate plugin?](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/)  Although this plugin automatically sets validation rules based on any inline attributes, you can also dynamically remove any rule using the `.rules('remove')` method.

Dynamically remove the `step` rule from the element matching `name="date1"` without removing any HTML attributes or changing the DOM.

```
$('[name="date1"]').rules('remove', 'step');
```

Note that the jQuery Validate plugin must already have been initialized on the page before this method is called.

> *this solution is valid only for one specific field with name="date1". Is it somehow possible to set unobtrusive validation rule which says something like "Ignore all step attributes"?*

You just need to change your selector to target all elements that contain a `step` attribute and enclose within an `.each()`.  jQuery Validate will only match first element in a targeted group, so using `.each()` is mandatory.

```
$('[step]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('remove', 'step');
});
```

Comment: I have to apologize that I accepted your answer, however other hidden error caused that your solution looked like it was working when actually that hidden bug was interrupting validation. When I resolved that bug, your solution still does not work and still `Step attribute on input type date is not supported` is thrown. I am really sorry for the inconvenience. Also I edited my answer with further details.

Comment: @Marmellad - FYI.  You cannot have input without a name attribute.   A name attribute is mandatory for this plugin to work properly no matter how you target.